# How to assign file names with spaces to vectors?

Tags: bash, vector, filenames, assign

I am an R user, and am trying to use for loops with a program that runs in bash (FFmpeg). It seems natural to me to create a vector and then use that vector in the for loop. For example, this is what I would do in R:

```
f <- c("File name that is identifier 01.avi", "File name that is identifier 02.avi", "File name that is identifier 03.avi")

for i in 1:length(f) {for loop}
```

**How do I assign names to a vector in bash?**

Here is what I tried and run to following problems:

```
f=["File name that is identifier 01.avi" "File name that is identifier 02.avi" "File name that is identifier 03.avi"]
bash: File name that is identifier 02.avi: command not found
```

Bash seems to identify my file names as commands and run them in this case

```
let f=["File name that is identifier 01.avi" "File name that is identifier 02.avi" "File name that is identifier 03.avi"]
bash: let: f=[File name that is identifier 01.avi: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[File name that is identifier 01.avi")
```

Here I am clearly doing something wrong.

If I do this for one file only, it works. With the brackets or without:

```
f=["File name that is identifier 01.avi"]
# echo $f
[File name that is identifier 01.avi]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, you can have an *array* by saying:

```
f=("File name that is identifier 01.avi" "File name that is identifier 02.avi" "File name that is identifier 03.avi")
```

and `${f[0]}`, `${f[1]}`, `{f[2]}` would return you the file names.

In order to loop through the array, you could say:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#f[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "${f[$i]}"
done
```

which would return:

```
File name that is identifier 01.avi
File name that is identifier 02.avi
File name that is identifier 03.avi
```

Alternatively, you could also loop by saying:

```
for i in "${f[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: I know that I should not thank in comments, but you answer was extraordinarily helpful. Thank you and keep on good work here at SO =)

Answer (score 1):

The only really sane way is to call the bash script with positional args (I don't know how to call programs from R so this is pseudocode):

```
exec(["bash", "-c", "echo one: $1, two: $2", "--", "eins", "zwei")
```

Here, the `--` marks the end of bash options and makes all subsequent parameters (in this case `eins` and `zwei`) positional arguments for the script itself.

There's one simple,portable,and secure way to embed words in the script: escape all critical (or, simply, all) characters of a single word by `\` and separate the words with whitespace:

```
system("myfunction my\ first\ arg\$\%\" my\ second\ arg\&\/\%")
```